# rewrite everything page on subdomain to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to create a rule who redirect everything what is behind subdomain to subdomain.

For example:

```
https://sub.domain.com/hkgfohkf
```

to

```
https://sub.domain.com/
```

This rule must be for each other subdomains.

I tried something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}^(([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+).domain.com/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$https://$1.domain.com [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work.

Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1.domain.com/ [NC,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I see that it will only work for sub.domain.com, but I want rule for all subdomains :)